# MYSQL select all rows with asian characters

Tags: mysql

On a database with customer information and in a table where names and addresses are mixed in latin and asian characters I'd like to select all that do (or don't) contain any asian characters. The data is UTF-8 encoded. Is that possible with MYSQL itself or do I need to write a custom script using PHP / Perl?

Comment: see [selecting-rows-with-non-latin-characters-in-mysql](http://www.gotoquiz.com/web-coding/misc/selecting-rows-with-chinese-characters-in-mysql/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page linked to in amdixon's comment had a working answer. Here it is so that we have it on SO:

To select all rows with non latin characters on col:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   col != CONVERT(col USING latin1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with regular expressions.  The idea is to look for all the simple characters that might be in string and use `^`.  So, to find unexpected (i.e. "Asian") characters:

```
where col regexp '.%[^0-9a-zA-Z.,:()& ].%'
```

The `.%` at the beginning and end are not necessary, but I like to have them so the patters are similar to `LIKE` patterns.

Comment: Your regexp just gave an empty result in my test